# How to work with picture to change from cold to hot on different points?

Tags: c#, usb, image

**Background:**
I have a microcontroller with 13 sensors for pressure reading in a foot on these 13 different points. The value read from each sensor goes from 0 to 1023 and is stored, then I send a string that contains these values over USB to a C# program running on the pc side.

**Question:**
On the pc side program using C#, how can I put a foot picture and make it change on these specific 13 points from cold to hot according with the value that came from the USB? That way showing the pressure in specific parts of the foot. Where more pressure more hot, where less pressure more cold. Don't need to show numerical values for hot or cold.

USB communication is fine, just need the picture treatment.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is usually called a [heatmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) so you'll probably find some additional information if you look into that term further.

I see three basic steps to your task:

1. Map the real-world sensor locations to pixel locations on a foot image (so you know which pixels to colour)
2. Once you have read all the sensors, build the heat map by mapping the sensor value to a colour (I'm assuming you want something like black at 0, bright red at 1023) and then do something like a [linear interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation#Interpolation_of_a_data_set) between the sensor locations relative to each pixel.
3. Blend the heat map value into the picture of a foot using alpha blending. You could also create a "heat map" bitmap image and just draw it on top of the foot image with a transparency set.

You could write to a Bitmap using something like [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287582%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).